# Python replacing partial string in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe similar to the following: -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date':['12/05/2014', '12/05.2015', '12/05//2016'], 'Day':['Monday','Tuesday','Thursday']})

          Date       Day
0   12/05/2014    Monday
1   12/05.2015   Tuesday
2  12/05//2016  Thursday
```

I want to clean the **Date** column where some dates are not in proper format. The dates are in string format which I will convert to date format after cleaning.

I found some help from other stackoverfolw posts and tried the following: -

```
1. Loop method

   for idx, row in df.iterrows():
       if '.' in df.loc[idx,'Date']:
           df.loc[idx,'Date'].replace('.','/')

2. Regex method

   df.Date.replace({'.','/'}, regex=True)
```

None of the above methods return the dates in desired format and return the dataframe unchanged. Is there another method which works?

Also, is there a method by which it is possible to replace in one command both kinds of strings ('.' and '//') with the correct string ('/')?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.str` API on the Date column to replace either a dot or multiple slashes with a single slash.  `.str.replace` uses regex by default.

```
df.Date.str.replace(r'[\./]+', '/')
```

Comment: Ah, sorry.  It was late when I wrote this one.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with `replace`:

```
df['Date'].replace(r'\D+', '/', regex=True)

0    12/05/2014
1    12/05/2015
2    12/05/2016
Name: Date, dtype: object

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].replace(r'\D+', '/', regex=True))
df

        Date       Day
0 2014-12-05    Monday
1 2015-12-05   Tuesday
2 2016-12-05  Thursday
```

Or, `str.replace`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.replace(r'\D+', '/'))

0   2014-12-05
1   2015-12-05
2   2016-12-05
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The pattern `\D+` will match character sequences which are NOT digits, and replace all of them with a single forward slash (this is what you want).

---

Another option is `extractall`, just for fun.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)')[0]
                         .unstack()
                         .set_axis(['month', 'day', 'year'], inplace=False, axis=1))

0   2014-12-05
1   2015-12-05
2   2016-12-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```